# @font-face IE9 font-weight doesn't work

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face

I'ver tried to embed a font with css @font-face. And i want use it as a bold font. But IE 9 doesn't display the font bold.

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Dauphin;
    src: url('dauphin.woff'),
         url('dauphin.ttf'),
         url('dauphin.eot'),
         url('dauphin.svg')
     ; /* IE9 */
     font-weight: normal;
}
.p {
     font-family: Dauphin;
     font-weight: 900;
}
```

Comment: What's the weight of the font in the font containers (dauphin.woff, .ttf, .eot, ...)? In the past, I've only seen embedded font files that contain a font with a single weight and style. When multiple weights or styles are needed, a different set of font files for each font variant is used (.woff, .ttf, .eot, ...).

Comment: You will have to set the font-weight to 900 instead of normal.

Comment: The font file is a normal font. When i set font-weight 900, the font will be displayed normal instead of bold

Comment: But it woorks in all other browers too

Comment: @Cirtrus: IE doesn't support using a different `font-weight` than was specified in a `@font-face` rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE doesn't support using a different `font-weight` than was specified in a `@font-face` rule.

**A set of font files for each font variant**

Typically, an embedded font file contains a version of the font with only one weight and one style. When multiple font variants are needed, a different set of embedded font files is used for each font variant. In the example below, only the `.woff` format is used, to simplify things. In practice, `.eot`, `.ttf`, and `.svg` will typically be used as well.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myFont.woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myFontBold.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
}
...
p {
    font-family: myFont;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h2 {
    font-family: myFont;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Supporting IE8**

However, IE8 has display issues when more than 1 weight, or more than 4 weights or styles, is associated with a font-family. To support IE8, use a different font-family for each font variant.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myFont.woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont-bold';
    src: url('myFontBold.woff');
}
...
p {
    font-family: myFont;
}
h2 {
    font-family: myFont-bold;
}
```

**Maximum cross-browser support**

For the optimal amount of cross-browser support, use the following syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myFont.eot');
    src: url('myFont.eot?#iefix')
             format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myFont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont-bold';
    src: url('myFontBold.eot');
    src: url('myFontBold.eot?#iefix')
             format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('myFontBold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('myFontBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('myFontBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
...
p {
    font-family: myFont;
}
h2 {
    font-family: myFont-bold;
}
```