# font-weight: bold with @font-face not working in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I'm using @font-face to define my own font:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: HelveticaNeue;
    src: url('fonts/helvlight_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local("☺");
    src: url('fonts/helvlight_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/helvlight_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/helvlight_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/helvlight_regular-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face{ 
    font-family: HelveticaNeue;
    src: url('fonts/helvlight_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: local("☺");
    src: url('fonts/helvlight_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/helvlight_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/helvetica_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/helvlight_bold-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

font-face rules was generated on Font Squirrel and afterwards I added font-weight and font-style rules. I use my custom font in CSS like this:

```
body {
    font: 16px HelveticaNeue, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

and it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

I tried this [@font-face works in IE8 but not IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9) to no success.

I also tried to change font-face name of bold style to HelveticaNeueBold and use it like:

```
h1 {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueBold;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

and it works but this is not what I want of course. Also adding !important after bold didn't help. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Personnaly, I always use a different name for different font-weight. Why don't you want to do like that if it works ? :D

Comment: @KaijuJu I't looks ugly and it defeats the purpose of font-weight. But it seems I don't have any other alternative, do I?

Comment: I'm not pro enough with CSS font-face properties but it seems to be the most common solution. Sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't support using a different `font-weight` than was specified in a `@font-face` rule.

You can read more about this here: [@font-face IE9 font-weight doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707827/font-face-ie9-font-weight-doesnt-work)

Comment: Thank you, somehow I didn't find the link you posted while I was searching.