# @font-face font-weight light not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I am trying to embed a font with css @font-face as a light font.  It works fine in Firefox, but not in IE11.  In IE11 font-weights bold and regular work fine, but not font-weight light.  In the following code, the text displays as Oswald regular:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('oswaldlight.eot');
  src: url('oswaldlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('oswaldlight.woff') format('woff'), url('oswaldlight.ttf') format('truetype');
}

div.h-title {
  font-size: 62px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

I have reviewed the the following similar posting, but the solution they recommend does not work.
[@font-face IE9 font-weight doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707827/font-face-ie9-font-weight-doesnt-work)
In the following code, the text actually displays as sans-serif:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Oswald-light;
  src: url('oswaldlight.eot');
  src: url('oswaldlight.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('oswaldlight.woff') format('woff'), url('oswaldlight.ttf') format('truetype');
}

div.h-title {
  font-size: 62px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: Oswald-light, sans-serif;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

Any ideas how I could resolve this?

Comment: Have you downloaded the font from online such as Google Fonts? I know with Google you have to select the different weights to include otherwise you cant change the weight

Comment: On a technical note to make your life at least a little easier: if you're targeting IE9 and up, [stop using multiple font formats](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff), just use WOFF. Everything supports it, no need to complicate things.

Comment: I downloaded from fontsc, and yes I did load the 3 weights Light, Regular, and Bold.  I actually tested fonts from FontSquirrel, 1001Fonts, and Fonts2U, and I was a little surprised to find that there were some differences in the way the fonts worked, but none solved this Light issue.  I also used EverythingFonts font-face-generator to generate the woff, eot, etc. formats.

Comment: Thanks for the note about WOFF.  Does that also apply for Firefox, Chrome, IOS?